# Replace zeros by the mean of n previours values

Tags: python, mean

I have the data set like this:

```
ID  qty  
10  3
10  4
10  4
10  0
10  6
11  7
11  2
11  0
11  5
11  6
11  1
11  0
11  9
```

The values should be grouped by `'ID'` and all zeros in the `'qty'` column should be replaced with the mean value of the three previos values. If there are less than three values before zero it shouldn't be replaced.

My expected output:

```
id  qty
10  3
10  4
10  4
10  3.67
10  6
11  7
11  2
11  0 -- it should be zero because id 11 has only 2 values before
11  5
11  6
11  1
11  4 -- this should be filled with rolling 3 average
11  9
```

Code which I have used:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['qty'] == 0:
      df.loc[i,'qty'] = df['qty'].iloc[(i-3):i].mean()
```

Comment: So is each ID its own 1D vector?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
rol = df.groupby('ID')['qty'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3).mean().shift().fillna(0))
df.loc[df['qty'] == 0, 'qty'] = rol
```

Output:

```
    ID       qty
0   10  3.000000
1   10  4.000000
2   10  4.000000
3   10  3.666667
4   10  6.000000
5   11  7.000000
6   11  2.000000
7   11  0.000000
8   11  5.000000
9   11  6.000000
10  11  1.000000
11  11  4.000000
12  11  9.000000
```